# Percentage value of a segment against segment total Power BI(DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

Hi guys, I am new to Power BI(DAX formulas) and I am attempting to calculate the percentage contribution of the sum of "count" where "category" = X and "item_no"=1 to the total of "count" across all categories where 'item_no' = 1.
The ideal mathematical statement here will be the (30/50)*100%
I intend to represent the percentage values in a chart showing percentage contribution of each distinct item_no to its total in the format as represented in the example above.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272781

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to approach this is

```
calculation over partial set / same calculation over larger set
```

Since you haven't made it clear what context you are trying to calculate this, I will assume it's a visual along these lines:

[image: Matrix Visual]

The measure I use here is

```
%ItemTotal =
DIVIDE (
    SUM ( Table1[count] ),
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[count] ), ALLEXCEPT( Table1, Table1[item_no] ) )
)
```

In the numerator, you have the sum *in the local filter context*. For example, in that top-left cell, this means all rows that match `item_no = 1` and `category = "X"`.

In the denominator, we do the same thing except we remove **all** filter context **except** the context we say to keep (`item_no`) so it includes all `category` values.

---

If you're trying to calculate that 60% outside of the context of a visual, then you can explicitly define what filters you want. For example, this should work in any filter context:

```
X%_Item1 =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table1[count] ),
        ALL ( Table1 ),
        Table1[category] = "X",
        Table1[item_no] = 1
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table1[count] ),
        ALL ( Table1 ),
        Table1[item_no] = 1
    )
)
```

---

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322212/dax-equivalent-to-t-sql-avg-overpartition-by/49323268#49323268) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192212/power-bi-dax-get-sum-of-a-column-based-on-another/53196626#53196626) for other ways to modify the filter context instead of `ALLEXCEPT`.