# Power BI: Percentage of total over multiple sliced categories

Tags: powerbi

I have data in the following format:

| Category1 | Category2 | Category3 | ... | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | D | X | ... | 2 |
| A | E | X | ... | 5 |
| A | E | Y | ... | 1 |
| B | D | Z | ... | 10 |
| B | F | X | ... | 2 |

I want to be able to show (in a card, probably) the amount of Category1 with value A (this category has only 2 values) as a percentage of all. But I have slicers/controls on all the other categories and I want this to reflect the values set on those at any time. There are quite a few categories.

For example, when no controls are applied, the sum of amounts with Category1=A is 8 and the overall total is 20, so the percentage would be 40%. With Category3 set to 'X', the sum of Category1=A is 7 and the overall total is 9, so the percentage would be 78%. But I want this to work with any combination of one or more slicers over many categories.

I've found this on SO - [Percentage value of a segment against segment total Power BI(DAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091373/percentage-value-of-a-segment-against-segment-total-power-bidax) - and tried creating a helper column to give the `Amount` where Category1=A and `0` if not. I've then tried to create a measure, using (pseudocode):

```
%Amount = DIVIDE ( SUM ( Table[HelperColumn] ), CALCULATE ( SUM (Table[Amount]), ALLEXCEPT(Table[Category1]) ) )
```

but it's showing 0%.

I'm new to Power BI and DAX and trying to replicate something I've done in another system, so I don't really understand what that formula is doing and I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 dax:
First is numerator(used to calculate stack amount based on probability of all 3 categories)[Please refer SS attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnnTD.png)

```
 numerator = 
var cat3Selected = SELECTEDVALUE(Stack[Category3])
var cat2Selected = SELECTEDVALUE(Stack[Category2])
var cat1Total = 
CALCULATE(
IF(and(ISBLANK(cat2Selected),ISBLANK(cat3Selected)),
 sum(Stack[Amount]),
   IF(and(not(ISBLANK(cat2Selected)), not(ISBLANK(cat3Selected))),
    CALCULATE(SUM(Stack[Amount]),Stack[Category2] = cat2Selected && Stack[Category3]=cat3Selected),
      IF(NOT(ISBLANK(cat2Selected)),
        CALCULATE(sum(Stack[Amount]),Stack[Category2]=cat2Selected),
        CALCULATE(sum(Stack[Amount]),Stack[Category3]=cat3Selected)
            )
        ))
)
return cat1Total
```

Second (Denominator ) is used to calculate stack amount for all category

```
*Denominator = CALCULATE(SUM(Stack[Amount]),ALL(Stack[Category1]))*
```

& then calculate % ,

```
*Percentage = DIVIDE(Stack[check msr],[normal all mSR],0)*
```

attached some screenshot for your reference: